# Extract images from pdf in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf

I am writing an application where a pdf file can be uploaded and the user will be shown some details of the pdf file(some text and images[png]) upon searching for the id of the pdf.

Now, in ubuntu, I am using `pdfminer` to convert to text and `pdfimages` to extract images. Now, here is the problem. In google app engine I am able to import pdfminer and use it for text extraction. But, I have not been able to extract images. pdfimages is available in ubuntu, but not as a python package.

Please help.

Comment: Google App Engine does not have any built-in modules that could support this. And as you figured, there's no alternative to `pdfimages` in Python AFAIK. You can write you own - here's [something](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/extracting_jpgs_from_pdfs.html) that could help.